# Extract the first object from a JSON array

Tags: json, jq

input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "title": "Hello"
  }
]
```

output:

```
{"name": "John","title": "Hello"}
```

Comment: jq .[0]  test.json

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of illustration, the following assumes a bash or bash-like shell:

```
$ jq -c first <<< '[ { "name": "John", "title": "Hello" } ]'
{"name":"John","title":"Hello"}
```